# jQuery readmore function not work in action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with [readmore jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js) for add more and less in my text like this :

JS:

```
$('.more').readmore({
  speed: 75,
  lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less</a>'
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="more">AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA </div>
```

But in action Not work for me!? how do can i fix this problem ?

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ba3kr57e/4/)**

Comment: Your jquery selector is wrong, for class selector you must use `.` (dot) before class name i.e. `$('.more').readmore({`

Comment: Even with that fixed it still does not work though.

Comment: It is not working in JSFiddle because "readmore.min.js" not getting downloaded properly and hence getting error "readmore" is not a function. Please download a local copy first and then upload it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: i change selector and add new mirror But this not work: http://jsfiddle.net/ba3kr57e/4/

Comment: Now I can see that there is no error. Could you please tell me what this readmore exactly do? I mean please explain how it should work and what problem you are getting.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: readmore add less and more link for truncate and slice text. but in my demo readmore not work and in result i see full text.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is not working for several reasons.

1. You never loaded jQuery. Readmore is a jQuery plugin and hence it requires jQuery to work. You should load a jQuery version 1.9.1. or greater for best support.
2. `readmore.min.js` is not being loaded properly. URL you added as a resource is missing http protocol. You should also make sure to load jQuery before Readmore.js.
3. Your text is too short, it wont get truncated. By default, plugin will truncate html element if its higher than 200px. On a widescreen monitor, your text will be too stretched so its height will be shorter than 200px and there wont be any need for truncation.

Here's a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9frr7ov/